# Duda sobre crear una funcion en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

estoy intentando crear una funcion que selecciona un promedio de duracion de peliculas en base a su categoria. Estoy escribiendo la siguiente funcion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `f_promedio` (f_categoria VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
DECLARE totalP DECIMAL;


SET totalP = (SELECT AVG(p.duracion) FROM peliculas p
JOIN peliculas_categoria pc ON p.id_pelicula=pc.id_pelicula
JOIN categoria c ON c.id_categoria=pc.id_categoria
WHERE c.nombre = f_categoria)
;
RETURN totalP;
END
```

Esta funcion la probaron mas de 3 compañeros de clase y se las compilo bien, pero a mi me tira error de sintaxis, alguna idea de que puedo estar haciendo mal?

El error que me dice es este: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 4

Comment: ¿Está intentando crear la función desde la línea de comando de MySQL?, quizás falte el comando `DELIMITER`.